# Concatenate NSMutableAttributedStrings in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, concatenation, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm going crazy with this :( Working in iOS6

I have an UITextView with a text in which each second I append an NSString to it and scroll to the last line appended. This way ->

```
        [textView setText:[textView.text stringByAppendingString:newText]];
        [textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([textView.text length], 0)];
```

I would like to use NSMutableAttributedStrings instead of NSString in order to format the text.

I have been searching everywhere but I haven't found anything. Is there any way to concatenate NSMutableAttributedStrings?? The current in the UITextView and the new one??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does appendAttributedString: not work?

Comment: Thank you very much! I've found a solution using that method :)